# Find n-th derivative using taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the n-th derivative of the following functions:

a) $f(x)= e^{x^2}$
b) $f(x)= e^{\frac{a}{x}}$
c) $f(x)= \arctan{x}$

Using

$f(x+h)-f(x) = h f{'}(x) + \frac{h^2}{2!}f{''}(x) + ...$

My initial idea was to find some recursive pattern but didn't have any luck with that.

Comment: Is $e^{a/c}$ intended ?

Comment: Don't you mean derivative *at a certain point* ?

Comment: sorry it is $e^{\frac{a}{x}}$

Comment: You might like to have a read of these pages: [Find an expression for  the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=e^{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2]), [Closed form of the $n^{th}$-derivative of $f(x) = \arctan x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476863/closed-form-of-the-nth-derivative-of-fx-arctan-x), [$n$th derivative of $e^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18284/nth-derivative-of-e1-x).

Comment: The last link above discusses the $n$-th derivative of $e^{1/x}$ rather than $e^{a/x}$, but you can use it with the chain rule to get what you want. That is, using the fact that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(bx)) = b^n f^{(n)}(bx)$ (via repeated chain rule), if you know an expression for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x):=e^{1/x}$, say $f^{(n)}(x) = g_n(x)$, then you can use this to get an expression for the $n$-th derivative of $e^{a/x} = e^{1/(x/a)}=f\left(a^{-1}x\right)$, namely $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(e^{a/x}\right) = a^{-n} g_n\left(a^{-1}x\right)$.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!